# Memory impact of including 3rd party libraries in iOS applications

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, memory, afnetworking-2

There are several excellent 3rd party libraries that make it easy to implement various things push notifications, networking, beautiful UI etc. But these libraries also contain several features that I don't use in my app.  Should I be worried about code bloat?  I.e

1. Will my app be substantially smaller if I decide to implement the part of the 3rd party library that I actually need on my own?
2. Will the memory used by app while running be substantially smaller since many of the properties in the 3rd party libraries that I won't be using will not exist if I implement it on my own.  (When I integrated a few 3rd party libraries and didn't too much fancy things on top I got a "memory warning" error which got me concerned)?

Comment: this would be something to be concerned about in the 80's probably, but your actual code and frameworks should have very little impact on the memory usage of your app, I would worry more about optimising your apps assets, eg images and stored data

Comment: your memory warning is most likely caused by something you are doing at run time, eg for loops allocating lots of objects before getting a chance to release, loading too many large images at once, etc. hard to say what exactly you are experiencing though from the information you have provided. should look at the instruments tools in xcode and see where all your memory usage is going to

Comment: Thanks, just loaded the following project on a 8GB iPhone5 https://github.com/relatedcode/RealtimeChat.  I saw the warning.  I noticed the project uses a ton of 3rd party libraries and was wondering is that is the case.  Instruments showed around 480K usage I think.